# How can I add a smoothscroll effect to the next page on my website

Tags: html, css, web

I want my website to have a smoothscroll to the next page, I have a button which I would like to use as smoothscroll. Using `<div id=""></div>` and this is the button     `<a href="Link here"><button type="button"><span></span>More info</button></a>`
and then I tried adding this in the CSS file: `scroll-behavior: smooth;` (in html, body)

Comment: Smooth scroll has been documented for decades. Did you search a bit? It's covered well on SO, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of libraries that can solve this problem for you and it will be compatible with many browsers and versions.

Here you can check an updated list:

https://www.cssscript.com/10-best-smooth-scroll-javascript-plugins/

But to answer your exact question, here you can see an example from w3schools working as expected using only css with `scroll-behavior: smooth;`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_scroll_behavior